# Java - Populate a JCombobox with SQLite database

Tags: java, database, swing, sqlite, jcombobox

I want to populate a JComboBox with a database column (SQLite).

My database connection is setup through a class called DatabaseConnection setup in anther package.

Here is how it looks like

```
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DatabaseConnection {
Connection conn = null;

public static Connection ConnectDB() {

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Established");
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        return conn;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

In my JFrame class I am creating following method, which according to a youtube tutorial should work

```
public void PopulateJCB()
{
    String queryString = "SELECT DISTINCT [Account Name] FROM main ORDER BY [Account Name]";
    try
    {
        Connection statJCBaccountname = DatabaseConnection.ConnectDB();
        Statement stmt = statJCBaccountname.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsJCBaccountname = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);

        while (rsJCBaccountname.next())
        {
            comboAccountName.addItem(rsJCBaccountname.getString(1));
        }

    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But it displays following errors at "comboAccountName.addItem(rsJCBaccountname.getString(1));"

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Type safety: The method addItem(Object) belongs to the raw type JComboBox. References to generic type JComboBox<E> should be 
 parameterized
- comboAccountName cannot be resolved
```

Please help!

Comment: Unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're expecting...

- `statJCBaccountname` isn't even in the code example you've provided, but the compiler is saying that the variable is undefined
- There is no such method as `createStatement` in the `DatabaseConnection` class

You need to resolve these issues before the program will compile.  I'd suggest staying away from YouTube tutorials unless you know the author.

Take a look at [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) for more details...

Comment: sorry, made a correction. statJCBaccountname is name of my statement.

Comment: `statJCBaccountname` but what type is it?  It's undefined, it's never been declared before?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpbQ0DCFF0M - THis video is where I saw. He just writes stat where I write statJCBaccountname

Comment: Okay I fixed it by adding Connection in front of statJCBaccountname. But the error remains on rsJCBaccountname

Comment: my bad. By putting ConnectDB in place of createStatement helped. But the error on rsJCBaccountname remains

Comment: The first one isn't to much to worry about, the second one is pretty much the same as all the others, you've failed to declare the variable `comboAccountName`